# Read from text file what's between parentheses - Java

Tags: java, string, text, text-files

So I want a modding system in my game, you ca put text files in a mod folder. I already have a system which will read text from a text file to a string. My text is formatted like this: `setSpeed(%s)`. Now I want to know which code I need to read what's between the parentheses and save it to an it variable.
Thanks.

Comment: If this is hard for you to do, then consider property files instead.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yeah, I was thinking about that. But really want it the my question says.

Comment: How many of these properties are you reading?

Comment: @gtgaxiola A much as the user puts into a mod file

Comment: Will you know which property is which? It seems to me a properties file is better for parsing (i.e. instead of `setSpeed(%s)` you do `speed=%s`  and you split each line by the `=` that way you get your key and value.

Comment: What exactly can be inside parenthesis? Can there be nested parenthesis? Will they require some kind of escaping? Will it be only one line or can it be two or more lines?

Comment: If you _ really_ want to do this then consider using an actual programming language with a JSR-223 binding and use `javax.script` classes to read the programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a string with your data, and further assuming there's no `)` inside the parenthesis, you could do...

```
String f = yourFile;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("setString\\(([^\\)]+)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(f);
while(m.find()) {
   System.out.println("setSpeed to " + m.group(1));
}
```

Will you only have setSpeed or other names as well?
P.s. include java.util.regex.*;

Comment: also setColumns and setRow